# How to prevent fullcalendar from "combining" events with the multiMonthPlugin plugin when canvas is resized

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar

Using the following options:

`plugins: [multiMonthPlugin], initialView: 'multiMonthYear',`

Is there an option to "force" the calendar to always at least display two rows of events? There is dayMaxEvents and dayMaxEventsRow but these only bound the upper limit of events per day/row. I have an issue where my fullcalendar days can either have 0, 1 or 2 events per day, and I'd like for it to always show the two events without the + link. What happens right now is that if the window is big enough, I'll see the two events, but if it gets too small, it starts combining them and the two events becomes a "+2" event with a link to expand them.

I tried several options, css doesn't seem to be the answer here. I feel like maybe I'm missing an option, or my calendar isn't configured correctly, or this plugin can't really do that.

edit: I have a codepen example here https://codepen.io/poljegui/pen/QWzZryB?editors=0010

Note how June 6th has two events, and for some reasons they're combining into a single one, I'd like to disable that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like the the **FullCalendar** library is somehow rerendering the page based on scrolling and page width changes.

So its not a dynamically built from scratch using modern methodologies (like FlexBox or CSS Grid) and it rerenders itself based on window events.

I've dabbled with it using the React build for the past 1 hour, and it seems not to support such feature, so you have to rely on some kind of hack (yeah unfortunately CSS hack). But I suggest you to use the `em` length type to accomodate to font and size changes of different screens (and future changes).

Here is my working code (but its in React using Next.js, but with the same configurations):

```
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import multiMonthPlugin from '@fullcalendar/multimonth'

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FullCalendar
          plugins={[multiMonthPlugin]}
          initialView="multiMonthYear"
          initialEvents={
            [
              {
                date: new Date(),
                title: "new day"
              },
              {
                date: new Date(),
                title: "new day"
              },
            ]
          }
          dayMaxEvents={2}
          dayMaxEventRows={2}
        />
        <style global jsx>{`
        .fc-daygrid-day-frame {
          min-height: 5em !important;
        }
        `}</style>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

In your case you just have to add a global css like so:

```css
<style>
  .fc-daygrid-day-frame {
    min-height: 5em !important;
  }
</style>
```